# Retrieve the name servers of a given domain with PHP

Tags: php, curl, dns, nameservers

I am trying to retrieve the name servers of a given domain, preferably in PHP.

I've tried a number of approaches but am unable to get any decent/consistent results and was wondering if anyone knew of a function or class that might help me achieve this?

For example, [this](http://code.google.com/p/php-whois-class/) whois class has some success, but fails to retireve the name server from dot com TLDs.

I was thinking that I could perhaps use Google's DNS server 8.8.8.8 in some way perhaps, but am unsure how?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about parsing console output of `nslookup` with PHP ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Hi, nslookup seems to only get my local cached DNS, which in  my case is my ISPs virginmedia, rather than the true nameservers which are ns.something.cloudflare.com etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is this function:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

```
$result = dns_get_record("stackoverflow.com");
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

For PHP On Windows:

```
$e = 'nslookup -debug www.google.com. 8.8.8.8';
```

For PHP On Mac and Linux:

```
$e = 'dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com.';
```

And then,

```
$o = array();
$r = -1;
$ip = exec($e,$o,$r);
if($r == 0) // success
{
    // do some regexp or explosion depending upon your output format to get the ip
    // here is for windows:
    $ip = trim(explode("Address:", $ip)[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but $ip in this instance returns an empty string. However the function in my answer does the job. Also if you see the first comment on the first answer, you'll see that nslookup does not retrieve the proper name servers, but rather the ISPs intermediary cached name server.

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime No, you are mistaken. `nslookup -debug` in case of windows,  is there for that specific purpose - to not use the local isp's cached name server. In this case the $ip was empty for other reasons: google has multiple ip addresses and when i explode for "address", i don't get anything.

Comment: i var dumped the returned $ip after exec and it was empty at any rate. Think the PHP function dns_get_record($domain); is infinitely more elegant too

Comment: ah $o array has all the goodies actually. I agree dns_get_record is easier to use. But, **how can you confirm that it doesn't use local dns server for resolving?** I mean, I searched and couldn't find anything relating to dns servers used for getting records.

Comment: Very true and a fair point. In my testing the nameservers were listed as xyz.ns.virginmedia.net etc when using exec nslookup, but yes, I agree you can't verify.

Comment: when using exec `nslookup {domain}` or `nslookup -debug {domain} 8.8.8.8` ? the latter will use `8.8.8.8` for resolution (_if that is not clear to you_).

Answer (score 1):

There are some PHP functions to do that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

perhaps you can use that.

Edit: On the left you have a complete list for **Network functions**.

Comment: As it happens, on the left was the rather handily named function, dns_get_record, did the trick, cheers.